# How to display current week number starting on a specific day in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, date

I'd like display the number of the week but starting on Wednesday. Do you know how could I do that ?

Example :
this_week is 13.

and next wednesday the week number will be 14 (on Tuesday it would still be week 13).

Currently my code is this :

```
function getWeekOfTheYear(d:Date):uint{
    var firstDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var dayOffset:uint = 9 - firstDay.getDay();
    var firstMonday:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, (dayOffset > 7) ? dayOffset - 7 : dayOffset);
    var currentDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
    var weekNumber:uint = (millisecondsToDays(currentDay.getTime() - firstMonday.getTime()) / 7) + 1;

    return (weekNumber == 0) ? getWeekOfTheYear(new Date(d.getFullYear() - 1, 11, 31)) : weekNumber;
    trace("week number is"+weekNumber);
}
```

But it's function that I've found on github and calculate the number of the week each Monday...

Thx for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, this code returns weeknumber starting on Wednesday.

```
function getWeekOfTheYear(d:Date):uint{
    var firstDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    //var dayOffset:uint = 9 - firstDay.getDay();
    //var firstMonday:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, (dayOffset > 7) ? dayOffset - 7 : dayOffset);

    var dayOffset2:uint = 11 - firstDay.getDay();
    var firstWednesday:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, (dayOffset2 > 7) ? dayOffset2 - 7 : dayOffset2);


    var currentDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
    var weekNumber:uint = (millisecondsToDays(currentDay.getTime() - firstWednesday.getTime()) / 7) + 1;

    return (weekNumber == 0) ? getWeekOfTheYear(new Date(d.getFullYear() - 1, 11, 31)) : weekNumber;
    trace("week number is"+weekNumber);
}
```

And following code returns weeknumber starting on specific day.

```
static var Sun:int = 0;
static var Mon:int = 1;
static var Tue:int = 2;
static var Wed:int = 3;
static var Thu:int = 4;
static var Fri:int = 5;
static var Sat:int = 6;
function getWeekOfTheYear(d:Date, startday:int):uint{
    var firstDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var dayOffset:uint = (7 + startday+ 1) - firstDay.getDay();
    var firstSpecificDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, (dayOffset > 7) ? dayOffset - 7 : dayOffset);

    var currentDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
    var weekNumber:uint = (millisecondsToDays(currentDay.getTime() - firstSpecificDay.getTime()) / 7) + 1;

    return (weekNumber == 0) ? getWeekOfTheYear(new Date(d.getFullYear() - 1, 11, 31), startday) : weekNumber;
}
```

How to use

```
trace(getWeekOfTheYear(new Date("2016/04/05"), Wed));   // Weeknumber starting on Wednesday
trace(getWeekOfTheYear(new Date("2016/04/06"), Wed));
```

Comment: EXACTLY ! Thank you very much !